# SailsJS 1.0 : Error in .create() for a model in Mongo with One Way Association to a model stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have a `Users` model stored in **MongoDb** and a `UserTypes` model stored in **MySQL**.

When I try to create a new User:

```
Users.create({name: "Shivam", userType: 1})
```

I get following error:

```
{ AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: Invalid replacement foreign key value provided for association (`userType`).  Cannot interpret `1` as a Mongo id.


(Usually, this is the result of a bug in application logic.)
For more info on Mongo ids, see:
• https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid
• http://sailsjs.com/support


    at _afterPotentiallyFinding (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-or-create.js:258:17)
    at _afterPotentiallyRunningAfterLC (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:328:20)
    at _maybeRunAfterLC (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:322:20)
    at _afterFetchingRecords (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:324:13)
    at _afterGettingPopulatedPhysicalRecords (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js:754:12)
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js:151:16
    at Object.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:254:18)
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1354:30
    at _tryToRunCb (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:542:20)
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:755:16
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:966:24
    at Function.handlerCbs.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:826:26)
    at Object.fn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/release-connection.js:77:18)
    at wrapper (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
    at Deferred.parley.now.flaverr.name [as _handleExec] (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1068:17)
    at Deferred.exec (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:679:10)
    at Deferred.switch (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1306:16)
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:242:92
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:123:18
    at Object.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/build-std-adapter-method.js:61:47)
    at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1354:30
    at _tryToRunCb (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:520:18)
  cause: 
   { AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: Invalid replacement foreign key value provided for association (`userType`).  Cannot interpret `1` as a Mongo id.
   (Usually, this is the result of a bug in application logic.)
   For more info on Mongo ids, see:
   • https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid
   • http://sailsjs.com/support
       at _afterPotentiallyFinding (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-or-create.js:258:17)
       at _afterPotentiallyRunningAfterLC (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:328:20)
       at _maybeRunAfterLC (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:322:20)
       at _afterFetchingRecords (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/find-one.js:324:13)
       at _afterGettingPopulatedPhysicalRecords (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js:754:12)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/help-find.js:151:16
       at Object.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:254:18)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1354:30
       at _tryToRunCb (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:542:20)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:755:16
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:966:24
       at Function.handlerCbs.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:826:26)
       at Object.fn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/release-connection.js:77:18)
       at wrapper (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
       at Deferred.parley.now.flaverr.name [as _handleExec] (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1068:17)
       at Deferred.exec (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:679:10)
       at Deferred.switch (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1306:16)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:242:92
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:123:18
       at Object.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/build-std-adapter-method.js:61:47)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1354:30
       at _tryToRunCb (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:520:18)
     name: 'AdapterError',
     adapterMethodName: 'create',
     modelIdentity: 'users',
     raw: 
      { Error: Invalid replacement foreign key value provided for association (`userType`).  Cannot interpret `1` as a Mongo id.
      (Usually, this is the result of a bug in application logic.)
      For more info on Mongo ids, see:
      • https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid
      • http://sailsjs.com/support
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/private/reify-values-to-set.js:95:35
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3253:15
          at baseForOwn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:2223:14)
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3223:18
          at Function.<anonymous> (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3526:13)
          at reifyValuesToSet (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/private/reify-values-to-set.js:68:5)
          at Object.fn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/create-record.js:58:7)
          at wrapper (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
          at Deferred.parley.now.flaverr.name [as _handleExec] (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1068:17)
          at Deferred.exec (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:679:10)
          at Deferred.switch (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1306:16)
          at Object.during (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/build-std-adapter-method.js:74:18)
          at _makeCallToDuringFn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:109:17)
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:128:7
          at Object.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:91:16)
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1354:30
          at _tryToRunCb (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:542:20)
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:755:16
          at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:966:24
          at Function.handlerCbs.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:826:26)
          at Object.fn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/get-connection.js:61:18)
          at wrapper (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19) code: 'E_CANNOT_INTERPRET_AS_OBJECTID' } },
  isOperational: true,
  adapterMethodName: 'create',
  modelIdentity: 'users',
  raw: 
   { Error: Invalid replacement foreign key value provided for association (`userType`).  Cannot interpret `1` as a Mongo id.
   (Usually, this is the result of a bug in application logic.)
   For more info on Mongo ids, see:
   • https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid
   • http://sailsjs.com/support
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/private/reify-values-to-set.js:95:35
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3253:15
       at baseForOwn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:2223:14)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3223:18
       at Function.<anonymous> (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3526:13)
       at reifyValuesToSet (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/private/reify-values-to-set.js:68:5)
       at Object.fn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/create-record.js:58:7)
       at wrapper (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
       at Deferred.parley.now.flaverr.name [as _handleExec] (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1068:17)
       at Deferred.exec (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:679:10)
       at Deferred.switch (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1306:16)
       at Object.during (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/build-std-adapter-method.js:74:18)
       at _makeCallToDuringFn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:109:17)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:128:7
       at Object.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/do-with-connection.js:91:16)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1354:30
       at _tryToRunCb (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:542:20)
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:755:16
       at /My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:966:24
       at Function.handlerCbs.success (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:826:26)
       at Object.fn (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/get-connection.js:61:18)
       at wrapper (/My_Project_Root//node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)


 code: 'E_CANNOT_INTERPRET_AS_OBJECTID' } }
```

However, `.populate()` works just fine:

```
Users.findOne('USER_ID_HERE').populate('userType')
```

yields the following result:

```
{
  id: "USER_ID_HERE",
  name: "Shivam",
  userType: {
    id: 1,
    label: "Student"
  }
}
```

Here are my Models:

**Users.js**:

```
module.exports = {

  datastore: 'mongoDb',
  attributes: {
   id: {type: 'string', columnName: '_id', required: false},

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      allowNull: true,
      maxLength: 50,
      minLength: 3
    },

    userType: {model: 'usertypes', required: true},
  }
};
```

and **UserTypes.js**:

```
module.exports = {

  datastore: 'default',
  attributes: {

    id: {type: 'number', autoIncrement: true},

    label: {
      type: 'string',
      maxLength: 255,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    users: {collection: 'users', via: 'userType'}

  }

};
```

where `default` datastore is `MySQL` and `mongoDb` datastore is `MongoDb`.

Here is the version info:

```
Version Info:
     : Sails          : v1.0.2
     : node           : v8.1.2
     : engine (v8)    : 5.8.283.41
     : openssl        : 1.0.2l
     : sails-mongo    : ^1.0.1
     : sails-mysql    : ^1.0.0
     : sails-hook-orm : ^2.0.0-16
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have also reported a Bug: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4484

Answer (score 1):

For others experiencing the same issue, here is a hotfix:

Set **`dontUseObjectIds: true`** for all models using **MySQL** adapter.

This seems to trick the `sails-mongo` adapter to not check for ObjectIds for Foreign Keys to Models using `sails-mysql` Adapter.

### Please note that this is NOT a proper solution, but just a workaround.